# How to count unique values within a row in R

Tags: r, unique-values

I have the following panel dataset in R which contains an ID variable and shows the last login details for that ID.

```
id name address last_log_june1 last_log_june2 last_log_june3 last_log_june4 last_log_june"n"
1    A           2020-06-01     2020-06-01    2020-06-03
2    B           2020-06-01      2020-06-01   2020-06-01
3    C           2020-06-01     2020-06-02    2020-06-03
```

In the above dataset, I want to calculate the unique number of times A, B, and C have logged in. How do I do that in R such that I only select the "last_log_date" variables and make R count the unique dates within them? I also want to add this count column to the dataset.

Looking forward to solving this!

Thanks,
Rachita

Comment: melt to long format and summarise

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_longer(dat, c(-id, -name), names_to = "variable", values_to = "dates")`

Answer (score 0):

You need the `unique` function and apply that on the rows.

```R
df <- data.frame(id = 1:3, name = LETTERS[1:3], 
                 last_log_june1 = c("2020-06-01", "2020-06-01", "2020-06-01"), 
                 last_log_june2 = c("2020-06-01", "2020-06-01", "2020-06-02"),  
                 last_log_june3 = c("2020-06-01", "2020-06-02", "2020-06-03"), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

n = 3 # number of "last_log_june" columns
result <- apply(df[, paste0("last_log_june", 1:n)], 1, function(x) unique(unlist(x)))
sapply(result, length) # shows a vector with the number of unique values
df$count <- sapply(result, length) # new column
```

Is that what you need?

Answer (score 0):

There are some functions in `dplyr`(version 1.0.0) package that may be of some help.

Assume you your data is called `df` with columns `ID`, `name`, `address`, and a series of columns start with `last_log_june`, and it's possible some `NA` values exist in those columns.

```
new_df <- df %>% rowwise() %>% ## indicate you want to apply functions on rows
  mutate(na_exists = ifelse(sum(is.na(c_across(starts_with("last_log_june"))))>0,1,0), 
         ## an intermediate variable na_exists to indicate whether or not there is `NA` in any of the columns
         unique_with_NA = length(unique(c_across(starts_with("last_log_june")),na.rm=T))
         ## if there is NA, the unique function will also count `NA` as a unique value
         unique_withno_NA = unique_with_NA-na_exists
         ## if you don't want NA counted as an unique value, then the final result should exclude it
) %>% select (-na_exists, -unique_with_NA)
      ## remove the intermediate variables
```

use of function `c_across(starts_with("last_log_june"))` will only consider columns start with `last_log_june`

Comment: Thanks so much, Xiang! I feel this should do the trick. However, I am getting an error "`c_across()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs." even though I have installed the dplyr package of the stated version. Any idea how to overcome this? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can try to use `dplyr::c_across()` in your code, this specifies `c_across()` function is coming from `dplyr` package. since `c_across()` only works in `dplyr 1.0.0`, you can run `sessionInfo()` in your console to double check its the correct version.

Comment: I tried doing the above. However, it is still showing me the said error. Thanks a lot for replying and helping out!